# Android-how to set the size of a view which is not added to any parent yet?

Tags: android, webview

I want to load a responsive web page in `Webview` and then extract the size of a specific element. the point is that the size of the element in Webpage changes as a function of the size of my `Webview`.
Since I want to do the entire process hidden and in background, I have defined a new `Webview` programatically and then need to define its `width` and `height`, but since it has not been added to any parent, it seems that using `.setLayoutParams(w,h)` is not working.
I'm doing these work in a separate class (not an `Activity`), so I'm not interested in adding the defined `Webview` to a parent and then make it `invisible`. How can I define the size of `Webview` in this case?!

Comment: Prefer defining layouts in xml rather than programmatically!

Comment: @SumitShukla of course! but in my case, it is not a nice solution

Comment: WHy it is not a preferred solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to calculate the height of HTML content first which you are going to load inside the WebView by a running script as,

```
webView.evaluateJavascript("document.getElementById('foo').offsetHeight",null);
```

remember to change "foo" by your element id in your defined HTML. Once you get the height to apply it to WebView and one more thing you must add the invisible WebView and load URL in it before executing the script.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the point is that first I have to set dimensions of the webview and then load the URL, because as I have mentioned, the size of the element in webpage changes as a function of the size of the webview, meaning that first the size of webview must be defined

Comment: Can you share the code where you trying to set params and its not working?

Comment: I could set it in another file 
public static WebView getWebView(Context context){
        WebView lWebView = new WebView(context);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100,100);
        lWebView.setLayoutParams(params);
        return lWebView;
    }